# c++ Most clean way to implement duplicate Binary Search Tree for complex type

Tags: c++, algorithm, object-oriented, comparative-review, binary-search-tree

I have tried to make my own implementation for a BST task I was given for a complex type (Transaction), that should be able to store duplicate values as well.

However, I am not sure if I have gone about it the right, way and if there is anything I could do to make my code cleaner / more to c++ best practices?

I was told multiset/multimap is something I could use and decided to go with multimap and everything seems to be working ok unless anyone can spot things I could have done better.

(Still very new to c++ and coding in general, just looking for some better coding practices).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

// Complex type used for the BST
class Transaction
{
private:
    std::string desc;
    time_t timestamp;
    std::string value;
    bool isWithdrawal;

public:

    Transaction(const std::string& value, std::string reason = "None.")
    : desc(reason), timestamp(time(nullptr)), value(value) { // timestamp is current date/time based on current system

        // Lambda to convert reason to lower to we can identify elements easier
        std::transform(reason.begin(), reason.end(), reason.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    
        this->isWithdrawal = (reason.find("withdrawal") != std::string::npos) ? true : false;
    } 

    std::string toString() const {
        // convert timestamp to string form
        const char* string_timestamp = ctime(&timestamp);
    
        if(this->isWithdrawal) { return "-- " + desc + ": -£" + value + " on " + string_timestamp;}
        else {return "-- " + desc + ": £" + value + " on " + string_timestamp;}
    }
    
    // Gets the amount, converts it to a double and returns it
    double getAmount() const {
        return std::stod(this->value);
    }
};


// The binary search tree implementation
class BST {
    
    struct node {
        multimap<const double, std::shared_ptr<Transaction>> data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    node* makeEmpty(node* t) {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        {
            makeEmpty(t->left);
            makeEmpty(t->right);
            delete t;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    node* insert(std::shared_ptr<Transaction> x, node* t)
    {
        if(t == NULL)
        {
            t = new node;
            t->data.insert(pair<const double, std::shared_ptr<Transaction>>(x->getAmount(), x));
            t->left = t->right = NULL;
        }
        else if(x->getAmount() == getFirstData(t->data)){
            t->data.insert(pair<const double, std::shared_ptr<Transaction>>(x->getAmount(), x));
        }
        else if(x->getAmount() < getFirstData(t->data)){
            t->left = insert(x, t->left);   
        }
        else if(x->getAmount() > getFirstData(t->data)){
            t->right = insert(x, t->right);   
        }
        return t;
    }

    node* findMin(node* t)
    {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else if(t->left == NULL)
            return t;
        else
            return findMin(t->left);
    }

    node* findMax(node* t) {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else if(t->right == NULL)
            return t;
        else
            return findMax(t->right);
    }

    void inorder(node* t) {
        if(t == NULL)
            return;
        inorder(t->left);
        cout << getFirstData(t->data) << " ";
        inorder(t->right);
    }

    node* find(node* t, double x) {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else if(x < getFirstData(t->data))
            return find(t->left, x);
        else if(x > getFirstData(t->data))
            return find(t->right, x);
        else
            return t;
    }

public:
    BST() {
        root = NULL;
    }

    ~BST() {
        root = makeEmpty(root);
    }

    void insert(std::shared_ptr<Transaction> x) {
        root = insert(x, root);
    }

    void display() {
        inorder(root);
        cout << endl;
    }

    std::string search(double x) {
        node* result = find(root, x);
        if(result != NULL) { return loopNode(result->data); }
        else { return "N/A"; }
    }
    
    

    // Gets the first pair key from a multimap
    double getFirstData(const multimap<const double, std::shared_ptr<Transaction>>& m){
        // Declare an iterator to first element
        auto itr = m.begin();
          
        return itr->first;
    }
    
    // Loop through a node and return its values
    std::string loopNode(const multimap<const double, std::shared_ptr<Transaction>>& m){
        std::string result;
        
        for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it){
            result += (*it).second->toString();
        }
        
        return result;
    }
};

int main() {
    BST t;
    
    t.insert(std::make_shared<Transaction>("1400", "Withdrawal"));
    t.insert(std::make_shared<Transaction>("1400.59", "Deposit"));
    t.insert(std::make_shared<Transaction>("1400.59", "Deposit - test"));
    t.display();
    
    std::cout << t.search(1400.59);
    
    return 0; 
}
```

IMPROVED VERSION

````
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <set>

// Complex type used for the BST
class Transaction
{
private:
    std::string desc;
    time_t timestamp;
    std::string value;
    bool isWithdrawal;

public:

    Transaction(const std::string& value, std::string reason = "None.")
    : desc(reason), timestamp(time(nullptr)), value(value) { // timestamp is current date/time based on current system

        // Lambda to convert reason to lower to we can identify elements easier
        std::transform(reason.begin(), reason.end(), reason.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
    
        this->isWithdrawal = (reason.find("withdrawal") != std::string::npos) ? true : false;
    } 

    std::string toString() const {
        // convert timestamp to string form
        const char* string_timestamp = ctime(&timestamp);
    
        if(this->isWithdrawal) { return "-- " + desc + ": -£" + value + " on " + string_timestamp;}
        else {return "-- " + desc + ": £" + value + " on " + string_timestamp;}
    }
    
    // Gets the amount, converts it to a double and returns it
    double getAmount() const {
        return std::stod(this->value);
    }
    
    // Overloading comparision operators by value (transaction amount)
    bool operator < (const Transaction& rhs){
      return this->value < rhs.value;
    }
    
    bool operator > (const Transaction& rhs){
      return this->value > rhs.value;
    }
    
    bool operator == (const Transaction& rhs){
      return this->value == rhs.value;
    }
    
    bool operator != (const Transaction& rhs){
      return this->value != rhs.value;
    }
};


// The binary search tree implementation
class BST {
    
    struct node {
        std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Transaction>> data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    node* makeEmpty(node* t) const {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        {
            makeEmpty(t->left);
            makeEmpty(t->right);
            delete t;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    node* insert(std::shared_ptr<Transaction> x, node* t) {
        
        if(t == NULL)
        {
            t = new node;
            t->data.insert(x);
            t->left = t->right = NULL;
        }
        else if(*x == getFirstData(t->data)){
            t->data.insert(x);
        }
        else if(*x < getFirstData(t->data)){
            t->left = insert(x, t->left);   
        }
        else if(*x > getFirstData(t->data)){
            t->right = insert(x, t->right);   
        }
        return t;
    }

    node* findMin(node* t) const {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else if(t->left == NULL)
            return t;
        else
            return findMin(t->left);
    }

    node* findMax(node* t) const {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else if(t->right == NULL)
            return t;
        else
            return findMax(t->right);
    }

    node* find(node* t, double x) {
        if(t == NULL)
            return NULL;
        else if(x < getFirstData(t->data).getAmount())
            return find(t->left, x);
        else if(x > getFirstData(t->data).getAmount())
            return find(t->right, x);
        else
            return t;
    }

public:
    BST() {
        root = NULL;
    }

    ~BST() {
        root = makeEmpty(root);
    }

    void insert(std::shared_ptr<Transaction> x) {
        root = insert(x, root);
    }

    std::string search(double x) {
        node* result = find(root, x);
        if(result != NULL) { return loopNode(result->data); }
        else { return "N/A"; }
    }
    
    
    // Gets the first pair key from a multimap
    Transaction getFirstData(const multiset<std::shared_ptr<Transaction>>& m) const{
        // Declare an iterator to first element
        auto itr = m.begin();
        
        return *(*itr);
    }
    
    // Loop through a node and return its values
    std::string loopNode(const multiset<std::shared_ptr<Transaction>>& m) const{
        std::string result;
        
        for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it){
            result += (*it)->toString();
        }
        
        return result;
    }
};


int main() {
    BST t;
    
    t.insert(std::make_shared<Transaction>("1400", "Withdrawal"));
    t.insert(std::make_shared<Transaction>("1400.59", "Deposit"));
    t.insert(std::make_shared<Transaction>("1400.59", "Deposit - test"));
    
    std::cout << t.search(1400.58);
    
    return 0; 
}
```
````

Comment: Your title is strange.  How do you know it's the "most clean way"?  And  if it is, why do you need a review.  And don't see any use of `std::complex`...

Comment: what do you mean by std::complex? what I mean by complex data type is that I am not doing BST on a int, string, float, etc but a class object e.g. Transaction object. I wanted a code review on what I could make cleaner/most efficient in my code. Thanks

Comment: Oh, an _aggregate_ type?  You probably need to be more careful with your words.

Comment: (English not being my first language, I find contemporary web machine translation from English to my 1st one helpful in not only checking if I said what I think. Translating back, I can see if a simpler way to translate what I'd say in my "native tongue" seems "close enough". (And yes, I tried with this comment. And was pleasantly surprised.))

Comment: (If and when you edit your post, please use C++. (And don't let your post end with a code fence - a newline does nicely.))

Comment: (See also: [How to create a binary search tree for complex type that allows duplicates in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70435030) on SO.)

Comment: @greybeard yes that was my original question, i wanted to know if my implementation is good or if i can make it better

Comment: It's interesting that you are implementing your own BST but internally using `std::multimap`, which effectively is a BST of its own.

Answer (score 2):

### Don’t Write `using namespace std`

Before anyone else says it, [here is the answer everybody always links to.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)  It’s good advice.

Personally, I think there are some times when it’s a good idea to import a few things from `namespace std`.  For example, you want to use STL classes such as `std::multimap<double, Transaction>` that are verbose to write out and a real hassle to change to another data structure.  So I often write something like

```
using TransactionDB = std::multimap< double, Transaction >;
```

This lets me change the implementation to a `multiset` if I want to do a comparison on the transactions themselves, or use a different allocator to avoid heap contention, or switch to a hash table if I don’t need the data to be sorted by key.  Most of the code will still work after changing one line.

I also still prefer `cout` to `std::cout`, `ptrdiff_t` to `std::ptrdiff_t`, and so on—especially for identifiers that I’ve been using since before there was a STL and that will never be confused for anything else.  A big part of the rationale of the answers I linked to is that there have been many different classes named `vector`, `map` and especially `string`, but nobody who isn’t deliberately obfuscating has ever redefined `cout`.

### Don’t Reinvent the Wheel

In the real world, you would just use `std::multiset`.  (This doesn’t officially have to be a self-balancing binary search tree, but it must have similar time complexity on its operations.)  To sort your objects, you want to implement `operator<` on your class.  If you cannot, an alternative is to write your own `Compare` class and use `std::multiset< SomeType, SomeTypeCompare >`.

Your current implementation has a `std::multimap` in each node with a `double` (holding the amount) as the key and a unique pointer to the `Transaction` as the data.  Storing a unique pointer rather than an object only makes sense if you are planning on transferring ownership.  If you’re not planning to pluck and delete nodes from the tree when you extract them, you probably want to `emplace` the transactions into the database, which constructs them in place, and return references or a `weak_ptr` to them.  Another alternative, if you expect the references to outlive the tree itself, is to store a `shared_ptr`.

I don’t see a reason to store a different tree in every node of your BST.  if you want to store a key and value in each node, you can just give them `key` and `data` members.

If you want to use the STL data structure internally, but wrap it in a different interface, the internal tree should be a `private:` data member, or you could possibly inherit using `: private std::multiset<Transaction>` or whatever you go with.

### Store Financial Data as Fixed-Point

You don’t want floating-point math on them, or round-off error.  Decide whether to store them as cents, mils or milrays and whether you need `long` or `long long` width.  Divide by 100, 1,000 or 10,000 when you print them, and use correct precision specifiers so $4.50 doesn’t print as $4.5.  You also don’t want amounts like $10.99998.

### Use the Right Keys

Do you really want to sort your transactions and iterate through them by the transaction amount?  Would it make more sense to sort them by date?  Or allow them to be sorted in different ways, by specifying a different `Compare` object?  If you do want to sort by the amount, does it make more sense to store this as a separate key variable than to make it part of the `Transaction` data, and define

```
bool Transaction::operator< (const Transaction& y)
{
  return amount < y.amount;
}
```

This particular member function can and should be declared as `const`, `constexpr` and `noexcept`.

Or you could define multiple classes implementing the comparison template parameter, allowing you to declare different trees that sort transactions by amount, time posted, customer ID, transaction type, and so on.

### Let your Trees be `const`

Right now, if you declare a `const BST`, you couldn’t do anything with it, because it has no `const` methods defined.  You also can’t use any of its methods in a `constexpr` expression.

You should mark methods as `const` or `constexpr` where you can, and perhaps add both a `const` overload that looks up and returns `const` data and a non-`const` overload that looks up and returns a mutable reference to data.

### If You Do Reinvent the Wheel, Do it Right

I get the impression that you were assigned this as a learning exercise that you want to solve yourself.

In that case, you should pick a self-balancing tree that you like, read how they work (but not look at an existing implementation until later), and implement that from scratch, without using STL set or map classes at all.  Red-black trees are a great, standard choice (especially if you don’t need to delete from them).  AVL or scapegoat trees are worth looking at.

### A Second Round

You wrote an improved version and requested my feedback, so here it goes.

You’re still doing the unusual thing where you both have a vestigial implementation of a BST with `left` and `right` node pointers, but you also separately store a STL binary search tree in the root node.  This isn’t what you want to do.  In the real world, you wouldn’t reinvent the wheel.  For the sake of this learning exercise, you want to write your own.  You might try to implement part of the same **interface** as the STL, using the same names for things both implementations have, such as `BST::value_type` and `insert`, but the spirit of the assignment is to write your own.

I would therefore recommend you delete all use of STL containers other than `string`, `string_view`, and possibly `vector` and `array`.  Look up the algorithms (but not the implementation) of a red-black tree and try to implement that.  That is, you’ll add two `bool` values like `left_is_red` and `right_is_red`.  (Alternatively, you could have a polymorphic node type, and implement a 2-3-4 tree, with very similar logic.)  Your original idea of storing a `std::unique_ptr<Transaction>` is a good one when you’ll be moving the data around between nodes as the tree self-balances, and returning a reference or `weak_ptr` to it.  Deleting values is more complicated than inserting them, so you might want to leave that for last.

You use C-style node pointers, which commits you to C-style memory management.  You would be better off using `std::unique_ptr<node>`, which is just as easy to test for validity, and manages its memory automatically.  You can move subtrees around with statements such as `right = std::move(subtree);`.  This is just as fast as assigning a C-style pointer.

#### Coding Style

You’re still `using namespace std;` after `#include <iostream>` and before your other headers.  I suspect that what you want is to import only the identifiers from `<iostream>`.  If so, there are ways to.

The most robust one, which you’ll often see me do, is to list the specific declarations you want to use.  I never really got into the habit of doing this the C++17 way, but the modern way to write this would be:

```
using std::cin, std::cout, std::endl;
```

I always make sure to list them in alphabetical order, so it’s easy to look one up.  This makes your code as future-proof as possible.  Good implementations of the standard library usually try to avoid declaring global identifiers that might clash with yours, although this has often happened in the past.  This method also has the advantage that you’ll see exactly what you’re using from each header file you include, and have a good idea when it’s safe to remove one, although I often leave a short comment such as

```
#using <utility> // For from_chars, move
```

There is also an older way to get only the identifiers from one header file in the global namespace.  You can write

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

This is how all all C++ programs were originally written.  At one point, the C++ standards committee actually thought it could break all existing code in the language, but compilers never stopped supporting this syntax.  Inevitably, the committee gave in and tried to regularize this de facto standard: every standard header comes in another version with `.h` that declares every identifier in both the global namespace and also with `::std`.

You name a method toString, but `snake_case` is more conventional here than `camelCase`.  The C++ standard library provides both `std::to_string`, which follows the current locale’s rules for a thousands and decimal separator, and `std::to_chars`, which is locale-independent.  The former might give you `1.234,56` rather than `1,234.56`.

You can still keep the interface that lets you convert either to a `double` value or a human-readable string.  Good job of encapsulation!  It would be much more annoying to make this change if you hadn’t thought of that.

#### Data Types

You often take `std::string` arguments, either by copy or by reference.  It’s good practice to accept `std::string_view` instead.  This is a light-weight object that it’s efficient to copy, and both C and C++ strings convert to it implicitly.  So, you could instead write

```
Transaction( const std::string_view value, const std::string_view reason = "None." )
```

One reason you might not want to do this is if you’re passing in an temporary value that it’s more efficient to move than copy.  For example, if you write `Transaction("10.99")`, the string `"10.99"` will convert to an expiring temporary.  If you write an overload that accepts `std::string&&`, you can make a more-efficient shallow copy, instead of a deep one.

Speaking of which, you have the right idea about storing monetary values in an exact-precision type and having a member to convert them to either a human-readable string or a floating-point number, but the format I would suggest is an integral type with one or two extra sig figs of precision.  I might store the result in a `long long int`, denominated in milrays, and then the conversion to dollars would be dividing by `10000.0`.  You might keep accepting monetary strings in your constructor, so you can parse them for validity, but you generally want to do math on them, not sort their string representations in alphabetical or lexicographic order.

#### `const` and `constexpr`

Right now, you have

```
bool operator < (const Transaction& rhs){
  return this->value < rhs.value;
}
```

This has two main flaws: it will not work with a `const Transaction` on the left, and it performs a `string` comparison.  If you store the value as a numeric type, and update the qualifiers, it could become something like,

```
constexpr bool operator< (const Transaction& rhs) const noexcept {
   return value_milrays < rhs.value_milrays;
}
```

This works for `const` objects on both sides of the comparison, enables constant-folding optimizations in expressions that can be evaluated at compile time, and also allows certain optimizations related to exception-handling.

### Follow-up on Return Types

Our discussion in the comments got me thinking about the return type of functions like `BST::find`.  The STL containers have a member function with the same name, and the Principle of Least Surprise would be that your container’s `tree.find(key_value)` would behave similarly.

The STL’s `find` returns an iterator, which can be dereferenced to get the value of the element.  Returning a `node*` isn’t great, both because `*tree.find(key_value)` gives you something completely different, and because this exposes the entire internal structure of the tree.

So, a quick fix would be to put this in the class definition:

```
using key_type = double;
using value_type = Transaction;
using iterator = value_type*; // Can be dereferenced, but NOT incremented!
using const_iterator = const value_type*; // Ditto.

constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept { return nullptr; }
constexpr const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return nullptr; }
iterator find(key_type x);
const_iterator find(key_type x) const;
```

This is the fastest way to get a STL-like interface, where code like this will still work:

```
 while ( const auto it = tree.find(current_key); it != tree.end() ) {
    const auto value = *it;
```

On the other hand, if you call `Transaction*` an `iterator`, programmers might think they can increment it to do an in-order traversal.  This will compile, but actually cause a memory-corruption bug.  If you wanted to make an iterator that works as expected, you would need to write your own class that wraps a `node*`, add a pointer in each `node` to the parent `node` to enable always finding the successor or predecessor, then write `operator++` and  `operator--` to find the successor or predecessor, respectively.  It would also need `operator*` to get the stored data and `operator->` to access its fields.  This is probably overkill here.

But if you’re going to make `BST::find` behave differently from `stl::set::find`, which is a reasonable choice, I’d suggest calling it something else, like `BST::lookup`.  Your interface should probably not return a `node*`.

Comment: So are you suggesting i change my node data member to std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<Transaction>> data; and then in the Transaction class overload the >, < and == operators?

Comment: @Davisor I have added an improved version with your feedback, (minus the std:: namespace issue which i will fix up later). Can you please tell me if it is better

Comment: @paigelarry342 if your data type is `std::unique_ptr`, I think you have to write your own comparator class that compares `*x` and `*y`,. You might also just store transactions, unless the API is planning to pluck them from the tree and have the client take ownership of them.

Comment: @paigelarry342 Nice work on the improved version. I’ve written a new review. I put the main point on top this time: you either want to learn to write your own BST, or use the STL containers. It doesn’t make sense to try to do some of both.

Comment: @paigelarry342 Or, if your tree doesn’t need to be self-balancing, you can just do a plain old BST. That’s much simpler than a red-black tree. It’d still be valuable to extend it to a red-black tree later.

Comment: thank you, i have updated you points with getting rid of std::, const etc However still wondering what you mean by I can do a plain BST, isn't that what I currently have? instead I just allow duplicate values as well. Thank you. For my application I dont need deleting of nodes (as you would never delete a transaction), i just need fast insertion and search.

Comment: I also found I cant use unique ptr for Node, as it gives me "use of deleted function"

Comment: @paigelarry342 You’re limited in what you can do with it, but you should be able to make this work. Without more context, you probably have to put `std::move` around a node that you’re moving or removing. Alternatively, I guess you could use `std::shared_ptr<node>`. It will just be a little less efficient.

Comment: Thank you, but for my actual BST does it seem fine, as it fits my application and provides search and insert capabilities which is what I needed. I guess you are right about making a balanced tree, however I can do some more research on this and mention in a report I need to do, "it would be preferable to create a red black / avl tree".

Comment: @paigelarry342 Okay. What I’d focus on first for improvement is: you shouldn’t have a second tree inside your tree. Your grader is likely to think it’s not in the spirit of the assignment. It’s also bad practice to be using raw pointers, which require manual memory management. Smart pointers would be better. It’s great you’re learning the STL containers, though, and I would try to follow its way of naming classes and methods, especially if you want to be able to use this data structure in future projects as a drop-in replacement.

Comment: @paigelarry342 Your lookup API should return `Transaction&` or `const Transaction&`, not ``node*``. If you were trying to return a `std::unique_ptr` to the caller, that also wouldn’t work.

Comment: sorry where have I used a  API?

Comment: @paigelarry342 I mean, the Application Programming Interface that you’re creating. I guess your definition of `find` is a lot like the STL’s, if you make `node*` your iterator type.

Comment: are you suggesting i change something? or is it fine how it is.

Comment: @paigelarry342 I slept on it and came up with some better advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Transaction(const std::string& value, std::string reason = "None.")
    : desc(reason),
```

Why are you passing `reason` **by value**?  If you meant to use the "sink" idiom, you are missing the call to `move` in the initializer list.

---

`this->isWithdrawal`
Don't write `this->` everywhere!  Your members are in scope when you are writing member functions.

`this->isWithdrawal = (reason.find("withdrawal") != std::string::npos) ? true : false;`

why would you ever write: `somebool ? true : false` ?  How is that any different from `somebool` by itself?  I think you're not internalizing that boolean values are values like anything else, not something that can only be used as a condition in a special kind of statement.

---

```
        std::string result;
        
        for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it){
            result += (*it)->toString();
        }
```

First, use a range-based `for` loop!
Second, this is just a transformation of each element.  Look at standard algorithms or "range" operators that let you traverse one collection and generate another.

---

```
   // Overloading comparision [sic] operators by value (transaction amount)
    bool operator < (const Transaction& rhs){
      return this->value < rhs.value;
    }
```

Why don't you allow comparing two `Transaction` objects when the one on the *left* is `const`?

If you are using C++20, you only need define a single three-way comparison and get all the relational operations available.

---

```
std::string toString() const {
```

Follow standards.  I can generally call (non-member) `to_string(x)` for any type of `x`... but not *your* type!  Besides being odd and different and something people need to remember, it will break any generic code where the type of `x` is allowed to by anything that works.

Comment: I pass reason by value as it cant be const reference as I am doing manipulation on it, in the body of the destructor

Comment: Also, why would I use ranged-based for loop? wouldn't the way I have done it do the exact same thing? Finally, what do you mean by "allow comparing 2 transactions", isn't that what the < is already doing? hope you can explain

Comment: "allow comparing 2 transactions"   read the qualification that follows, _when the one of the left is `const`_.  Try it in your test code; you can't.

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you use a ranged-for loop?  It more directly states what you want, is simpler to read and code, and less error prone.  `for (auto x : m)    result += m.toString();`  You don't actually need the iterator within the body; it is just busywork.

Comment: "I pass reason by value as it cant be const reference as I am doing manipulation on it, in the body of the destructor"  that literally makes no sense.  What does the destructor's implementation have to do with the parameter passed to the constructor?  The object's `desc` member is not related to the `reason` argument.  I think you are confused somewhere as to what is happening in the code.

Comment: sorry i mean i am doing work on reason in the constructor's body, as you can see iam checking if reason has a "withdrawal" string in it.

Comment: @paigelarry342 OK, I understand that.  But reading the contents of `reason` (or, `desc` after it has been copied or moved into place) does not mean that you have to pass `reason` by value.  You can certainly _find_ things in a `const string&` !